# Is there a possibility to store an interesting question with answers in some kind of a "Favorites" area of my stackoverflow.com account?

Tags: support, bookmarks

I won't like to use browser bookmark feature, because I use several browsers and read Stack Overflow from different locations. Is there any button to mark a question as interesting, so they could be stored somewhere in my account, so I could access these questions next time?

Comment: Ha! I like how somebody just demonstrated this feature on this very question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can click the star next to the question, under the votes, and it will appear on your favorites page.

[image]