# How to save Stack Overflow questions in my favourites list?

Tags: support, bookmarks

How can I save some important questions in my favourites list?

Comment: Click around. I'm sure you'll find it.

Comment: I would close as a duplicate of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/how-do-i-add-a-question-in-my-favorite-list-closed), but it's closed and has pretty weak answers. This should be the new [faq] for this question

Comment: @Michael Mrozek - I don't think that question is very useful; one answer says to use "Favorite Button" (kind of a circular definition?) and the other says "using **start** " instead of "star"

Comment: @Richard I know, that's why I said it has pretty weak answers and this should be the new faq entry; that question is currently tagged [faq] despite not being very helpful

Comment: @Michael Mrozek - Ok, total "reading your comment" fail on my part :)

Comment: Very similar to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61000/is-there-a-possibility-to-store-an-interesting-question-with-answers-in-some-kind

Answer (score 7):

When you see a question you like then click the star.

[image]

Then when you want to see all of your favourite questions.  Go to your profile (click your username at the top of the page)  Then click the favourites tab:

[image]

Comment: Should be freehand circles ;)

Comment: @ChrisF: Yeah, I was about to say... maybe Barry is new here?  :)  @Barry: See the Freehand circles entry on [The Many Memes of Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775) to see what we're going on about.

Comment: @ChrisF, @Bill the Lizard : Didn't know about the freehand circles.  Updated my pictures - just because thats how I roll :-)

Comment: @Barry - don't worry, you updated the screenshot with a more appropriate annotation.

Comment: @Barry: Masterfully done! :)

Comment: When I visit stackoverflow.com, I don't have a link at the top that says "Barry."  What is wrong with my computer?!

Comment: @James McNellis - Just to clarify - i have updated my answer.  No more now. No more. :-)

Comment: Must you be located in London to participate in Stack Overflow? This seems somewhat restrictive.

Comment: Don't make me do it - don't make me put *another* picture on....

Comment: I'm not going to be 27 for a few years; I guess I'll have to wait before I can star posts :(

Comment: @Michael: I'm long past the age of starring posts.  :(

Answer (score 0):

Click a star image under the number of votes in question area.