# Is it possible to make a list of favourite question (with answer) in stackoverflow

Tags: support, bookmarks

if not, there should be a way such as, "Add to Favorite" or Marks as Fav. So we can later see our favorite questions and answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save Stack Overflow questions in my favourites list?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63736/how-to-save-stack-overflow-questions-in-my-favourites-list)

Answer (score 2):

you can mark a question favourite by clicking on a star. There isn't a way to favourite an answer as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Note the star icon next to each question. That's exactly what you're asking for.

You can see all your favorites in your profile, in the "favorites" tab.

Answer (score 1):

There is. Click on your name at the top of the page, then click "favorites". You'll see a list of all your questions that you've marked as favourite.

To mark a question as a favourite, however, click the star below the score.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer here

[How to save Stack Overflow questions in my favourites list?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63736/how-to-save-stack-overflow-questions-in-my-favourites-list/63739#63739)