# Add to favorities feature on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to save Stack Overflow questions in my favourites list?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63736/how-to-save-stack-overflow-questions-in-my-favourites-list)

I want to add a few questions as favorites and I am able to do that, but how to retrieve the same.

I want to know if Stack Overflow has some add-to-favorites kind of feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to favorites by clicking the *star* symbol below the up/down voting arrows to the left of the question body.

Access favorites by going to your profile page (click on your name in the top bar) and click the "Favorites" tab located below the "About Me" box.