# bookmark stackoverflow questions

Tags: support, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to save Stack Overflow questions in my favourites list?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63736/how-to-save-stack-overflow-questions-in-my-favourites-list)

Sometimes I come across a question I may want to refer back to in the future as it contains useful advice. Am I missing something or is there no method provided for marking specific questions as "favourites". The only way would be to bookmark them in my browser which is a shame.

Answer (score 4):

There's a star to the left of your question, under the voting buttons. Clicking it will mark it as a favorite, and it can then be accessed from your profile.

Comment: Aww, why did this not transfer over to my account with the shift?

Comment: It should, wait for a while for the script to run.