# Query regarding "favouriting" posts

Tags: support, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to save Stack Overflow questions in my favourites list?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63736/how-to-save-stack-overflow-questions-in-my-favourites-list)

If I find post on Stack Overflow that I find really useful, is there a way to save it to my profile such that I can refer to it at a later point? I figure there must be a more efficient way than bookmarking everything!

Comment: maybe add it to your favorites by clicking on the gray star?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the star next to the question. Then it appears in the favourites in your user profile.

There is no star for answer just questions.